# Can I trigger a Lambda function or SNS event in response to an AppSync GraphQL Mutation?

Tags: aws-lambda, graphql, amazon-sns, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

AWS AppSync/GraphQL subscriptions coupled with AWS Amplify sound amazing, since out of the box you can subscribe all your clients to high-level domain events specified in your schema.

Though it seems like a natural extension that there should be a way to broadcast all those events to a service like lambda or SNS to react internally to those events. Maybe you want to log the events, re-index or aggregate updated data, or send an email or push notification to a user. Just like DynamoDB Streams allows you to trigger a lambda upon to updates on a table. Is anyone aware of a good way to achieve this?

There appears to be no AppSync trigger source for lambda, but it seems like there might be a couple of ways to do this otherwise:

1. Create a long-running process/service on ECS/Fargate that subscribes to every mutation it wants to broadcast to SNS/Lambda. Not ideal as you would have to manage and scale that process yourself.
2. Use DynamoDB Streams as a lambda trigger. However, a DynamoDB table change event is lower-level than a GraphQL mutation event, and this assumes your only data source is DynamoDB, whereas AppSync/GraphQL can plug into many other data sources.
3. Create lambda resolvers for every mutation that also broadcast the event to SNS/Lambda. For simply broadcasting SNS events, perhaps there's a clever way to use pipeline resolvers to attach a reusable resolver to every mutation...

I'm not sure how the Amplify framework powers their @searchable transformer, whether its #2 or #3, or something else altogether, but it seems like that's in the same ballpark (re-indexing the data in Elasticsearch in response to an update). I do remember hearing you can write your own transformers ... perhaps one could write their own transformer @broadcasted that also broadcasts all mutation events to SNS

I'm surprised I haven't seen much if any discussion surrounding this topic. If anyone has some good ideas or if I'm thinking about this the wrong way let me know.

Comment: Have you looked at Pipeline resolvers? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/pipeline-resolvers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to trigger lambda functions based on incoming mutations.

Like you mentioned in option 3 - lambda resolvers can achieve this functionality but if what you would like to do is invoke a common lambda that publishes to SNS as a step in the execution - then you can utilize Pipeline Resolvers. Where the 'common' lambda function will be the data source for the step in your pipeline and then have the regular resolver you would use for Dynamo/ES/Aurora Serverless.

Docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/pipeline-resolvers.html

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @Ashwin! I think I've been a little confused about the language surrounding "types" and "fields". I kept hearing about pipeline resolvers in the context of resolving "fields", which I thought to mean resolving the fields of types during queries only. In the documentation you linked there's a good example showing that a mutation called signUp is also a "field" on the Mutation "type". Everything is really just a type or field. So setting up a reusable pipeline resolver that broadcasts a mutation event to SNS or even calls a lambda directly is something entirely supported.